# Summatory functions for fractional parts

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

**Notation:**
$$ \{x\}\ :=\ x-\lfloor x\rfloor $$

---

APF-functions $\ \tau(n)\ $ for $\ 2<n\in\mathbb N,\ $ and $\ \xi(n)\ $ for $\ 3<n\in\mathbb N,\ $ are defined as follows:

$$ \tau(n)\ :=\ \sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\,\left\{\frac nk\right\}\qquad\qquad\text{and}\qquad
     \qquad\xi(n)\ :=\ \sum_{k=2}^{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}\ \left\{\frac nk\right\} $$

These functions are sensitive to their arguments being or not a prime.
Locally, primes seem (how true is it?) dominate over their neighborhoods. In this spirit,

**Question:**   Do you already know or can you prove non-obvious results about
the APF-functions $\ \tau\ $ and $\ \xi\,?$

Comment: What does APF stand for? I can't find it by a web search.

Comment: (@YCor, please, see the other thread for a partial answer).

Comment: See also: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429286/n-th-ipj-functions

Comment: I've removed my Q. about ipj-functions. I would remove present one too but the system protects the Answer to this Q. Oh, well...

Comment: (But I did upvote @GMfromMO Answer nevertheless; plus, it's accepted).

Comment: @paulgarrett, I am into mathematics, I am not into "winning friends" at all. (My friendships are just a byproduct of them being honest, straight, authentic, ... -- otherwise, forget it!). #### The whole idea of MO-points is sick, especially in the hands of people who know nothing about fair play. #### Some my friends use for their name just upper case initials, and they are still my friends. I never ask them to divulge their "acronym", and certainly would never press them about it or "punish" for this.

Comment: "please, see the other thread for a partial answer." What other thread? And, can't you just change the title to something more informative?

Comment: The other thread (MO-question) is gone. But substitute above $\ \sum\ $ by $\ \prod,\ $ and you'll have it, that's all.

The titles of the present thread, and of the removed one, are more informative than 80% of the titles around MO. The mathematical domain was identified. And, in the context of number theory, word "function" has a narrow meaning. We are talking too about some specific number-theoretical functions.

Comment: Never mind, I took care of it.

Comment: I read the posts on this page and have no idea what “APF function” means.

Comment: I have my author's right to my title. Don't violate them. Also, mathematicians should be tolerant and humane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your $\tau(n)$ and $\xi(n)$ are essentially the same as the [divisor summatory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function), often denoted by $\sigma(n)$. Indeed, we have
$$\sigma(n)=\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{k\mid m}1=\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]=2\sum_{k=1}^{\left[\sqrt{n}\right]}\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]-\left[\sqrt{n}\right]^2.$$
That is,
$$\sigma(n)=\tau(n)+n+1=2\xi(n)+2n-\left[\sqrt{n}\right]^2.$$
Note that we have rather precise estimates for $\sigma(n)$, this is what the Dirichlet divisor problem is about. See the above Wikipedia page for more details. For example, Huxley (2003) proved for any $\varepsilon>0$ that
$$\sigma(n)=n\log n+(2\gamma-1)n+O_\varepsilon(n^{131/416+\varepsilon}).$$
In particular, these functions $\sigma$, $\tau$, $\xi$ are **not sensitive** to their arguments being prime or not prime.

**Added.** In my response, $[x]$ denotes the integral part of $x$, not the fractional part as in the OP's post. Sorry about that. At any rate, it is straightforward to relate the sum of the integral parts of $n/k$ and the sum of the fractional parts of $n/k$, because the sum of $n/k$ has a well-known asymptotic expansion.

Comment: My earlier (removed by me) Q. had $\ \prod\ $ instead of $\ \sum.\ $ Possibly, IPJ-functions from my removed post are new or relatively new -- possibly, they have some research potential.

Comment: @WlodAA See my "Added" section. Sorry about the mismatch in notation.

Comment: Sorry for (temporarily) forgetting about the standard fractional part notation. I'll correct it. #### The local domination mentioned in my Q. has a good chance to be at least partially true.

Comment: @WlodAA: The arithmetic nature of $n$ does not influence your functions $\tau$ and $\xi$ too much. For example, your $\tau(n)$ is really $\sum_{k=1}^n n/k-\sigma(n)$, which by my last display is $(1-\gamma)n+O_\varepsilon(n^{131/416+\varepsilon})$ for any $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: however, GH, I was stressing word **locally**. The smoothness of the estimate seems to be a global result.

Comment: Well, my numerical experiment tells me that you, GH, are right.